# Matrix calculations using Excel INDIRECT

Tags: excel, regression, vba

I would like to run a regression in excel using `LINEST` function combined with `INDIRECT`.  I need to select the time series between dates and multiply `Y` and `X` with an Index before I run the regression.

```
Date    | Y | X | Index
30/06/1990   1.21    2.20    -   
30/09/1990   0.73    1.33    -   
31/12/1990  -0.07    1.31    -   
31/03/1991   1.64    0.80    1.00 
30/06/1991  -0.14    0.61    1.00 
30/09/1991   4.13    2.37    1.00 
31/12/1991   0.71    0.78    1.00 
31/03/1992   0.95    0.78    -   
30/06/1992   1.61    0.78    -
```

By using the above data, I need to use the `LINEST` function from 31/03/1991 until 30/06/1992 but for dates only when the index is 1.

My idea was to use `INDIRECT` to specify the date range, multiply the `LINEST( INDIRECT(Y)*INDIRECT(Index),INDIRECT(X)*INDIRECT(Index),0,0)` but I have a error.

Thank you for your help

Comment: It would be useful to know what your actual error is? Just saying 'I have a error' doesn't give us much to go on

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `INDIRECT`. `INDIRECT` requires the argument to be text of a cell name. e.g. `=INDIRECT("A1")` would return whatever is in cell A1. `=INDIRECT(X)` where X is a number would return an error, specifically `#REF!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cells in the target range will always be consecutive, try...

H2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER:

```
=SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$10>=F2,IF($A$2:$A$10<=G2,IF($D$2:$D$10=1,ROW($A$2:$A$10)))),1)
```

I2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER:

```
=LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$10>=F2,IF($A$2:$A$10<=G2,IF($D$2:$D$10=1,ROW($A$2:$A$10)))),1)
```

J2, confirmed with just ENTER:

```
=LINEST(INDEX($B:$B,H2):INDEX($B:$B,I2),INDEX($C:$C,H2):INDEX($C:$C,I2),0,0)
```

[image]

Otherwise, try the following instead...

H2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER:

```
=LINEST(N(OFFSET($B$2:$B$10,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$10>=F2,IF($A$2:$A$10<=G2,IF($D$2:$D$10=1,ROW($B$2:$B$10)-ROW($B$2)))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(IF($A$2:$A$10>=F2,IF($A$2:$A$10<=G2,IF($D$2:$D$10=1,1))))))),0,1)),N(OFFSET($C$2:$C$10,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$10>=F2,IF($A$2:$A$10<=G2,IF($D$2:$D$10=1,ROW($C$2:$C$10)-ROW($C$2)))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(IF($A$2:$A$10>=F2,IF($A$2:$A$10<=G2,IF($D$2:$D$10=1,1))))))),0,1)),0,0)
```

[image]

However, for Excel 2010 and later, MODE.MULT can be used instead...

H2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER:

```
=LINEST(INDEX($B:$B,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF($A$2:$A$10>=F2,IF($A$2:$A$10<=G2,IF($D$2:$D$10=1,ROW($A$2:$A$10)*{1,1}))))))),INDEX($C:$C,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF($A$2:$A$10>=F2,IF($A$2:$A$10<=G2,IF($D$2:$D$10=1,ROW($A$2:$A$10)*{1,1}))))))),0,0)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I am using excel 2007 and the MODE.MULT function is not available.Do you have any proposal how to modify your formula so I can use it for 2007?

Comment: I've added two additional methods.  The first one can be used if the cells in the target range will always be consecutive.  Otherwise, use the second one.